# Audio Player using flash, appears on every page rather than only the page added to

Tags: javascript, html, flash, audio, media-player

I added an audio player to my project and the player supports flash. I added to a 5 page app, to the 5 th page but it appears in the middle of the app and on every page. I have to delete it. If anyone could guide me to help get this player visible only in one page rather than every. It never disappears, irrespective of the number of page I am on.

Here's the HTML:

http://shrib.com/9ZMmFhrY

Here's the project am looking to add:

http://www.codebasehero.com/files/music-player-1.0.1/demo/

Comment: Where is the code to help you on?

Comment: I added an audio player to my project and the player supports flash. I added to a 5 page app, to the 5 th page but it appears in the middle of the app and on every page. I have to delete it. If anyone could guide me to help get this player visible only in one page rather than every. It never disappears, irrespective of the number of page I am on.

Here's the HTML:

http://shrib.com/9ZMmFhrY

Here's the project am looking to add:

http://www.codebasehero.com/files/music-player-1.0.1/demo/

Comment: Please add a minimal version of the code to produce the problem to the question.

Comment: I did not get it I am sorry